# Ocultar el referente (referer) usando javascript o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, referer

Intento ocultar la [cabecera HTTP `Referer` (referente)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)usando este *script*, pero no funciona:

```js
function open_link(url)
{
    instance = window.open("about:blank","_self");
    instance.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="+url+"\">");
    instance.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton" onclick="open_link('https://www.whatismyreferer.com/')">Continuar</button>
```

Buscando en *google* no se encuentra una manera exacta para lograrlo. Espero me puedan dar alguna idea en PHP o javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes cambiar las [políticas de referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) de tu página agregando simplemente la siguiente etiqueta [`<meta name="">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name) a la cabecera:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="same-origin" />
```

Con eso el navegador no enviará la cabecera `Referer` en ningún enlace que sea pulsado en la página que te lleve a un sitio externo, manteniendo la funcionalidad interna de la web.

Con la siguiente se desactiva completamente:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Puedes ver los ejemplos de uso y comportamiento en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Ejemplos).

PD: No funciona en Edge legado ni en Internet Explorer.

También se puede realizar la misma función haciendo uso del atributo `rel` para elegir el [tipo de enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types):

```
<a href="https://www.whatismyreferer.com/" rel="noreferrer">Pulsar aquí</a>
```

Comment: gracias por la información